# less.js: Cannot read property 'lineNumber' of undefined

Tags: less

When setting `dumpLineNumbers: "comments"` using less.js, I'm getting a error that reads

`Cannot read property 'lineNumber' of undefined in test.less`

Here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        less = {
            env: "development",
            dumpLineNumbers: "comments"
        };
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" media="all" 
          href="test.less" />
    <script  
     src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.0/less.js">     
    </script>
```

I've tried this with less.js versions 1.7.5 and versions 2.5.0, with the same results.  I'm iterating on the less code to see what part it's crashing on, but I was wondering if anyone else had hit this problem?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this error. The following line should throw it: https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/tree/debug-info.js#L20 Something inside `test.less` should trigger it (possible some kind of @import directive). Are you able to show the contents of your `test.less` file too?

Comment: can you give the code so that we can figure out your problem?